# javascript no muestra la hora en html5

Tags: javascript, html5, xampp, date, localhost

Tengo el siguiente **script** para mostrar la hora pero no hace nada cuando ejecuto **index.htm**. El archivo **js** se llama **reloj.js** y sí, lo estoy llamando dentro de **html**, pero no se ejecuta el código y no más me muestra los dos **":"** separadores del horas y minutos porque esos se están declarado dentro del **html**.

```js
    (function(){

 var actualizaHora = function(){
  var fecha = new Date(),
   horas = fecha.getHours(),
   ampm,
   minutos = fecha.getMinutes(),
   segundos = fecha.getSeconds();

  var pHoras = document.getElementById('horas'),
   pAMPM = document.getElementById('ampm'),
   pMinutos = document.getElementById('minutos'),
   pSegundos = document.getElementById('segundos');



   if(horas >= 12){
    horas = horas - 12;
    ampm = 'PM';
   }
   else
   {
    ampm = 'AM';
   }

   if(horas == 0){
    horas = 12;
   };

   pHoras.textContent =  horas;
   pAMPM.textContent = ampm;

   pMinutos.textContent = minutos;
   pSegundos.textContent = segundos;
 };

 actualizaHora();
    }())
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
     <div class="widget">
      <div class="reloj">
      <p id="horas" class="horas"></p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p id="minutos" class="minutos"></p>
      <p>:</p>
      <div class="caja-segundos">
        <p id="ampm" class="ampm"></p>
        <p id="segundos" class="segundos"></p>
      </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Por ahora todo parece estar correcto, debe ser algo que no estamos viendo...

Comment: Revisa la consola para buscar si hay error en otro código, porque este sí funciona.

Comment: la consola dice: No se puede establecer la propiedad 'textContent' de nulo
     en actualizaHora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que se debe a la posición en tu html donde cargas el script y su ejecución, en tu caso puede que tengas algo como esto:

```
<head>
   <script src = "tuScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Si lo tienes asi, entonces el problema surge porque estas intentado acceder a los elementos `HTML` y guardarlos antes de que siquiera existan.

Para solucionarlo hay dos maneras, la primera es encerrar todo tu codigo dentro de una funcion onload de la ventana:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  (function(){

    var actualizaHora = function(){
        var fecha = new Date(),
            horas = fecha.getHours(),
            ampm,
            minutos = fecha.getMinutes(),
            segundos = fecha.getSeconds();

        var pHoras = document.getElementById('horas'),
            pAMPM = document.getElementById('ampm'),
            pMinutos = document.getElementById('minutos'),
            pSegundos = document.getElementById('segundos');



            if(horas >= 12){
                horas = horas - 12;
                ampm = 'PM';
            }
            else
            {
                ampm = 'AM';
            }

            if(horas == 0){
                horas = 12;
            };

            pHoras.textContent =  horas;
            pAMPM.textContent = ampm;

            pMinutos.textContent = minutos;
            pSegundos.textContent = segundos;
    };

    actualizaHora();
    }())  

}
```

```html
<script src="reloj.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="widget">
  <div class="reloj">
  <p id="horas" class="horas"></p>
  <p>:</p>
  <p id="minutos" class="minutos"></p>
  <p>:</p>
  <div class="caja-segundos">
    <p id="ampm" class="ampm"></p>
    <p id="segundos" class="segundos"></p>
  </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

La segunda es poner tu script al final del body, asi:

```
<body>
  ...
  ...
  <script src = "tuArchivo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: si primero estaba llamando el scipt sin antes crear el html por eso no se ejecutaba

Comment: De nada amigo Manny, me alegra poderte haber ayudado, no de hecho si se ejecutaba solo que se ejecutaba antes de que tus elementos html necesarios fueran creados (mas no toda la pagina), puesto que seguro hay otros elementos que antes de poner el script ya estaban creados.

Comment: Siempre es bueno tener en cuenta todas las condiciones antes de echarle la culpa al código. +1